# How do I show that the final point estimates of a variable satisfy the invertibility conditions?

Tags: self-study, estimation, forecasting, econometrics

I cannot seem to figure out how to `"identify the final point estimates of theta1 and theta2 and verify that they satisfy the invertibility conditions... [and] identify the final point estimate of delta"`. All of these are obviously values in the model 
$Y_t=\text{ ...}$

I am given a MINITAB output of the estimation, diagnostic checking, and forecasting of daily readings using the model. I want to be able to figure it out myself, so I wont post the actual tables I am given to make sure I understand it when I have to do it again later.

I know how to find point estimates...but how does the 'final' point estimate differ? And how is it calculated? Lastly, how do I show that they satisfy the invertibility conditions?